# Overwrite a hosted feature using SDE View

Tags: esri, arcpy

I am attempting to overwrite a Hosted Feature layer using SDE View. First, I get the layer ID from the portal and connect it to the portal. Secondly, I connect to my SQL and select the view I want. Thirdly, I create a new temporary view with the query and attempt to overwrite my hosted feature layer. Once the layer is overwritten, I delete the temporary view. My code is working fine, and I can see the updated item in the portal. Still, when I check the attribute data, it is not updated. It still shows the total number of attributes when I published it manually. My old view had 51 rows, and my new temp view had 57 rows. The code is working without any error, and the layer is updated, but the layer still shows the old data (51 rows). The service definition file is also updated in the portal, but I'm not sure if I need to do it in the code as well.

The code works, but it is not actually updating the data, and I am not sure what to do. Please see my attached code for reference -

```py
#Import Modules
import arcpy
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayerCollection
import pyodbc
import traceback
import arcpy.mp

# Connect to ArcGIS Online organization or Portal for ArcGIS

gis = GIS("Service URL", "Username", "Password")
un = gis.properties.user.username
# confirm that the user has logged in successfully
print('Logged in as: {}'.format(un))

#Variables - Web layers
itemid = "e5008676768687d"

# Set the connection properties
server_name = "ABC"
database_name = "XYZ"
username = "EEE"
password = "EEEE"
instance = "TD-G20\\ESRI"
sde_connection_path = r"C:\\Users\\ABC\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\Desktop10.8\\ArcCatalog\\SQL.sde"
connection = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(sde_connection_path)
view_to_select = "Cities"
arcpy.env.workspace = sde_connection_path

# Check if the view is selected
if arcpy.Exists(view_to_select):
    print("SDE View Selected Successfully.")
else:
    print("View does not exist")

#Creating a query on Cities View
#query = "SELECT CAST(Status AS smallint) FROM Cities WHERE Status = 1";
#result = connection.execute(query) # Execute the query

view_name = "Cities_QueryviewTemp"  # Temporary View with a query

# Check if the view already exists
if arcpy.Exists(view_name):
    print("View already exists.")
else:
    # Create the view with the query applied
    arcpy.management.MakeTableView("Cities",view_name, where_clause="Status =1")
    result = arcpy.management.GetCount("CEP_QueryviewTemp")
    row_count = int(result.getOutput(0))
    print("Total number of rows:", row_count)

# Verify if the view was created successfully
if arcpy.Exists(view_name):
    print("Temporary View selected successfully.")
else:
    print("Failed to create the view.")

# Overwrite Hosted Feature Layer
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
dataitem = gis.content.get(itemid)
flayercol = FeatureLayerCollection.fromitem(dataitem) #Establishing a feature collection
flayercol.manager.overwrite(view_name)

print('Cities Web Layer Overwrite Successfully!')

# Delete the temporary view
arcpy.Delete_management(view_name, "VIEW")
print('Temporary View Deleted')
```